# python + script failed regarding to cryptography under /usr/lib64/python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptography, airflow, rhel

**I create the following python script**

this python script will read the file `/lpp/airflow/.sec/rmq_pass` to var - `pass_hash`

and will decrypt it to `decrypted_pass`

```
more security_test.py
import sys
import os
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key_file = "/lpp/airflow/.sec/key"
rmq_pass_file = "/lpp/airflow/.sec/rmq_pass"

key = open(key_file, 'r')
f = Fernet(key.read())

pass_hash  = open(rmq_pass_file, 'r')
#decrypting the password from "pass_file" file using the key from the "key_file".
decrypted_pass = f.decrypt(pass_hash.read())
ConnStr = "amqp://airflow:" + decrypted_pass  + "@localhost:5672//"
```

when I run the script
its failed on /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py , or any under `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography`

we try to re-install the package cryptography , but this didn't help

and idea what is could be ?

```
python  security_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "security_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    decrypted_pass = f.decrypt(pass_hash.read())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, ttl)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 117, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 101, in _verify_signature
    h = HMAC(self._signing_key, hashes.SHA256(), backend=self._backend)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._ctx = self._backend.create_hmac_ctx(key, self.algorithm)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 207, in create_hmac_ctx
    return _HMACContext(self, key, algorithm)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py", line 34, in __init__
    key_ptr = self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(key)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a str or unicode or bytearray object
```

IMPORTANT NOTE - on other machine this script is working fine

what is the best way to resolve it ? by remove all modules and install them again ? or by re-install python ?

Comment: Airflow will drop support of Python 2.7 from version 2.0 (lot of big changes, coming in Q3/Q4 of this year) onwards. Maybe the best solution is migrating to python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was installed by `pip`, then this issue is due to having an out-of-date `cffi` package (I was able to reproduce this problem by force-installing `cffi` 1.5 in a `virtualenv`). Newer versions of `cryptography` require `cffi >= 1.8`, but `pip` does not always resolve that properly (depending on a variety of other scenarios). You can `pip install -U cffi` to see if that resolves it, but in general you should strongly consider running Python code inside of a `virtualenv` and not installing packages into the global package space. The OS package manager assumes that it owns global packages and you can cause many issues with your install if you mix and match distribution packages with `pip` installs.

Comment: when I download the " pip download  cffi"  , its download only the cffi-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl , how to download the new version?